# get number of lines which has particular record from last hour log

Tags: shell-script, grep, logs, date

I need to get number of lines which has particular record from last hour log .

log record looks like this.

09:28:03.155 [pool-2-thread-1030]-Rcvd msg {src='90000000',dst='101',msg='2500FREE',trxId='1511927883155JKVQ'}
09:28:04.211 [pool-2-thread-1036]-Rcvd msg {src='90000001',dst='101',msg='ON6',trxId='1511927884211OCLJ'}
09:28:06.381 [pool-2-thread-1044]-Rcvd msg {src='90000002',dst='101',msg='i89',trxId='1511927886381GLRI'}

condition I should match and get count 
"Rcvd msg"

I have tried this, but no output ,
grep "^$(date -d -1hour +'%H %M')" recvdmsg.log | grep 'Rcvd msg' | wc -l

Answer (score 0):

Since the timestamp in your text is "09:28:03.155" what about adding a colon to the date?

date -d -1hour +'%H:%M'

Comment: this can be done with dummy values                                                         sed -rne '/00:00:/,/00:59:/p' /pathtolog/recvdmsg.log | wc - l

Comment: Hi , my logic changed.      below code works fine for me.                                                                    #!/bin/bash

flag=1
date1=$(date --date="1 min ago" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
nowdate=$(date --date="1 min ago" +%H:%M)
echo "$date1"
echo "$nowdate"

count=`grep "$nowdate:" /data/tsdc/alco2/hutch-smpp-service/log/audit/recvdmsg.log | grep "Rcvd msg" | wc -l`

echo "$count"